# JQuery not showing/hiding element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm simply trying to have JQuery show/hide a div. I've tried using Javascript instead and that still does not work. I've tested to make sure that everywhere in my JS script is being reached. It just isn't applying and I don't know why. Thank you for any help you can give.

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  startup();
  $('select').material_select();
  $('ul.tabs').tabs();
  $('.collapsible').collapsible({
    accordion: false // A setting that changes the collapsible behavior to expandable instead of the default accordion style
  });
});

function startup() {
  $("#Assignments").hide();
  $("#ClassView").hide();
}

$('.datepicker').pickadate({
  selectMonths: true, // Creates a dropdown to control month
  selectYears: 15 // Creates a dropdown of 15 years to control year
});

function tabswitch(x) {
  if (x == 1) {
    $("#Calender").show();
    $("#Assignments").hide();
    $("#ClassView").hide();
  } else if (x == 2) {
    $("#Calender").hide();
    $("#Assignments").show();
    $("#ClassView").hide();
  } else if (x == 3) {
    $("#Calender").hide();
    $("#Assignments").hide();
    $("#ClassView").show();
  }
}
```

CSS

```
#sidebar p {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
}
#sideInterior p {
  color: black;
}
.tabs a:link {
  font-family: monospace;
  color: white
}
.tabs a:hover {
  color: gray;
}
.tabs a:visited {
  color: white;
}
.tabs a:active {
  color: white;
}
body {
  background-color: #bdbdbd;
}
.Accordion {
  background-color: white;
}
li {
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.5/css/materialize.min.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="newStyle.css">
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.js'></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.5/js/materialize.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="JS.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf8">
  <title>Scheduling_Main</title>
</head>
<nav>
  <div class="nav-wrapper blue darken-4">
    <a href="#" class="brand-logo">Scheduling Project</a>
    <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
      <li><a href="Profile.html">Profile</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="Settings.html">Settings</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="Help.html">Help</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<body>
  <div id="2ndNav" class="row nav-wrapper blue">
    <div class="col s3 blue" id="sidebar">
      <p>Add to your schedule
        <p>
    </div>
    <div class="col s9" id="tabSpace">
      <ul class="tabs blue">
        <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#Calender" onclick="tabswitch(1)">Calender</a>
        </li>
        <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#Assignments" onclick="tabswitch(2)">Assignments</a>
        </li>
        <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#ClassView" onclick="tabswitch(3)">Class View</a>
        </li>
        <div class="indicator white" style="z-index:1"></div>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <!--start of sidebar-->
    <div class="col s3">
      <ul class="collapsible popout" data-collapsible="accordion">
        <li class="Accordion">
          <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">add</i>Add semester</div>
          <!--start of "add semester"-->
          <div class="collapsible-body">
            <div class="input-field">
              <input id="Semester_Title" type="text" class="validate">
              <label for="Semester_Title">Semester Title</label>
            </div>
            <div class="startDate">
              <label for="Semester_Start">Start Date</label>
              <input id="Semester_Start" type="date" class="datepicker">
            </div>
            <div class="endDate">
              <label for="Semester_End">End Date</label>
              <input id="Semester_End" type="date" class="datepicker">
            </div>
            <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="action">Submit
              <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
            </button>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="Accordion">
          <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">add</i>Add course</div>
          <!--start of "add course"-->
          <div class="collapsible-body">
            <div class="input-field">
              <select>
                <!--list of semesters go here-->
                <option value="" disabled selected>Choose the semester</option>
                <option value="1">Option 1</option>
                <option value="2">Option 2</option>
                <option value="3">Option 3</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="input-field">
              <input id="Course_ID" type="text" class="validate">
              <label for="Course_ID">Course_ID</label>
            </div>
            <div class="input-field">
              <input id="Course_Title" type="text" class="validate">
              <label for="Course_Title">Course Title</label>
            </div>
            <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="action">Submit
              <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
            </button>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="Accordion">
          <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">add</i>Add assignment</div>
          <!--start of "add assignment"-->
          <div class="collapsible-body">
            <div class="input-field">
              <select class>
                <!--list of classes go here-->
                <option value="" disabled selected>Choose the class</option>
                <option value="1">Option 1</option>
                <option value="2">Option 2</option>
                <option value="3">Option 3</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="input-field">
              <input id="Assignment_Title" type="text" class="validate">
              <label for="Assignment_Title">Assignment Title</label>
            </div>
            <div class="endDate">
              <label for="Due_Date">Due Date</label>
              <input id="Due_Date" type="date" class="datepicker">
            </div>
            <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="action">Submit
              <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
            </button>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
      <!--tab stuff goes here-->
      <div id="#Calender" class="col s9">
        <p>Calender Test</p>
      </div>
      <div id="#Assignments" class="col s9">
        <p>Assignment Test</p>
      </div>
      <div id="#ClassView" class="col s9">
        <p>Class Test</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the element(s) to make sure the style is being applied to them, and also to see what css rules are possibly overriding it forcing it to be hidden or not hide?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed your code. Please see if this is what you want:

[enter link description here][1]

Just change id name.

[1]: https://jsfiddle.net/tyqsa12u/`enter code here`

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML elements should not have `#` in front of their ids. Its just used in CSS selector to refer to them.

Replace

```
<div id="#Assignments" class="col s9">
    <p>Assignment Test</p>
</div>
<div id="#ClassView" class="col s9">
    <p>Class Test</p>
</div>
```

with

```
<div id="Assignments" class="col s9">
    <p>Assignment Test</p>
</div>
<div id="ClassView" class="col s9">
    <p>Class Test</p>
</div>
```

and it should work.